# Unable to import userlibrary

Tags: java, eclipse

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="MacRoman" standalone="no"?> <eclipse-userlibraries version="2">
> <library name="USC_KFS_LIB" systemlibrary="false">
>     <archive path="/java/lib/JUnit/junit.jar"/>
>     <archive path="/java/lib/Log4j/log4j-1.2.14.jar"/>
>     <archive path="/java/lib/TOMCAT/jsp-api.jar"/>
>     <archive path="/java/lib/TOMCAT/servlet-api.jar"/>
> </library></eclipse-userlibraries>
> ```

This is the content of my file when i try to import this file as user library it works in my machine a while not in machine b.
both have same configuration .

Comment: the selected file is not valid userlibrary data file

Comment: The end tag `</eclipse-userlibraries>` is missing in the snippet - is it missing in the original file too?

Comment: no its there.
i have edited the content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. By Changing the Encoding to UTF-8